# How to generate a series of number by function of sample in R, with given different probability in each try?

Tags: r, probability, sample

For example I have a vector about possibility is

`myprob <- (0.58, 0.51, 0.48, 0.46, 0.62)`

And I want to sampling a series of number between 1 and 0 each time by the probability of `c(1-myprob, myprob)`,

which means in the first number in the series, the function sample 1 and 0 by (0.42, 0.58), the second by (0.49, 0.50) and so on,

how can I generate the 5 numbers by sample?

The syntax of

`Y <- sample(c(1,0), 1, replace=F, prob=c(1-myprob, prob))`

would have incorrect number of probabilities and only 1 number output if I specify the prob;

while the syntax of

`Y <- sample(c(1,0), 5, replace=F, prob=c(1-myprob, prob))`

would have the probabilities focus on only 0.62(or not I am not sure, but the results seems not correct at all)

Thanks for any reply in advance!

Comment: @Mael's answer is the same approach I would take, but it's worth noting I think your second try is giving unexpected results because of `replace=F`.  Try again with `replace=TRUE` and see if that lines up more with your expectations.

Comment: Simply changing `replace=TRUE` to `replace=FALSE` will not work because `sample()` requires *one* probability for each element, i.e. one for 1 and one for 0.

Answer (score 3):

If `myprob` is the probability of drawing 1 for each iteration, then you can use `rbinom`, with `n = 5` and `size = 1` (5 iterations of a 1-0 draw).

```r
set.seed(2)
rbinom(n = 5, size = 1, prob = myprob)
[1] 1 0 1 0 0
```

Answer (score 2):

[Maël](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13460602/ma%C3%ABl) already proposed a great solution sampling from a binomial distribution. There are probably many more alternatives and I just wanted to suggest two of them:

#### runif()

```r
as.integer(runif(5) > myprob)
```

This will first generate a series of 5 uniformly distributed random numbers between 0 and 1, then compare that vector against `myprob` and convert the logical values `TRUE`/`FALSE` to 1/0.

#### vapply(sample())

```r
vapply(myprob, function(p) sample(1:0, 1, prob = c(1-p, p)), integer(1))
```

This is what you may have been looking for in the first place. This executes the `sample()` command by iterating over the values of `myprob` as `p` and returns the 5 draws as a vector.